# What makes this code so slow? (for project Euler q45)

Tags: python, algorithm, math

I just solved and found the answer for problem 45 on project euler, however the solution took twenty minutes to compute. Other similar solutions take less than a second to find the solution.

[The problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=45)

My code:

```
import time

def is_triangular(n):

    triangle_index = (((8 * n + 1) ** 0.5) + 1) / 2
    if triangle_index % 1 == 0:
        return True
    return False

def is_pentagonal(n):

    pentagonal_index = (((24 * n  + 1) ** 0.5) + 1) / 6
    if pentagonal_index % 1 == 0:
        return True
    return False

def is_hexagonal(n):
    hexagonal_index = (((8 * n + 1) ** 0.5) + 1) / 4
    if hexagonal_index % 1 == 0:
        return True
   return False


number = 40756
while True:
    if is_triangular(number) and is_pentagonal(number) and is_hexagonal(number):
        print(number)
        break

    number += 1
```

Comment: Why are you doing all these `% 1` calculations?

Comment: Also what is the use of importing `time` if you aren't using it? Unless this is just a portion of your code and you use it elsewhere?

Comment: I'm doing them to check if that index that is calculated is an integer. If it isn't it means n isn't a triangle/pentagonal/hexagonal number.@UnholySheep

Comment: `% 1` doesn't do what you think it does. If you want to check if it's divisible, then you'll want to `% 2 == 0` instead of `/ 2`, `% 6 == 0` instead of `/ 6`, etc..

Comment: you could compute `(((8 * n + 1) ** 0.5) + 1)` only once for starters. But knowing project euler problems, bruteforce isn't the solution. You have to find some criteria to avoid computing all the numbers

Comment: `0.0 % 1` is `0.0` in python, so that is not valid for integer checking.

Comment: OP probably means `int(x) == x`

Comment: once you solved it, you have access to the forum, where there probably are a lot of python solutions. Look for them.

Comment: as always with project euler, there's some analytical solution to the problem: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HexagonalPentagonalNumber.html

Comment: I get it: you've got it the other way round. Generate the triangle/... numbers with integer series and get the intersection of the values instead of testing all the values. That should be fast. I remember solving that, and that's probably how I did (but it was 7 years ago)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of going through every number and checking if its triangular, pentagonal and hexagonal. Generate Hexagonal numbers and for each hexagonal number check if its triangular or pentagonal.

You can generate hexagonal numbers by using the formula for hexagonal numbers and increasing n by 1.

Comment: Yep, you're right. Used a generator to yield the hexagonal numbers and now the solution takes around 20ms to find. I really should stop relying on pure compute power.

Comment: Glad i could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Because you are looking to every natural number after 40755. Limit the case to a subset of real numbers: if you know already that a number is not hexagonal you can discard it already, for example.

Since the hexagonals are in the less dense subset, start by looking to numbers in that set. Then, check if they're pentagonals, and eventually check if those are triangular too.

main function example:

```
hex = 144
while True:
    number = hex*(2*hex-1)
    if is_hexagonal(number):
        if is_pentagonal(number):
            if is_triangular(number):
                print("Found: {}".format(number))
                break
    hex += 1
```

There are other modifications that can be done in the Python code, but I focused on the algorithm only.